# SDWebImage - image not showing

Tags: ios, swift, image, nsurlsession, sdwebimage

I want to get an image from a url. When using Apple's api's it works but when I use `SDWebImage` (version 3.8) I get an error.

Using Apple's api (this works):

```
    if let url = NSURL(string: testURL) {
        if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url) {
            let testImage = UIImage(data: data)
             cell.personAvatar.image = testImage
        }        
    }
```

Using SDWebImage (does not work):

```
 cell.personAvatar.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: testURL)!, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "testImage")!) { (image, error, SDImageCacheType, url) in
        cell.personAvatar.image = image
    }
```

I am making these calls inside of: 
`override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell`.

The error I get when using SDWebImage is:
`Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLKey=`

Any ideas why this is not working?

Comment: Tell me which iOS version you are using?

Comment: I figured it out.. Had to use `SDWebImageManager` and give authorization since the server required it.